# Laravel global session helper is not working

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using Laravel version 5.4.36 and global session helper is not working anymore.

Here is what I did: when a logged in user access a controller function, I need to save some data and when user refresh(reload) the page then I want to keep that data but it seems global session helper is not doing this. Is something I'm doing wrong? My session is file based.
I followed [official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session) but unfortunately no help :)

Storing data with `$request->session()->put(...)` is useless in my case because whenever user reload the page data lost.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WatchController extends Controller{

     public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware(['auth']);
     }

    public function watchAds(Request $request){

       $userId = Auth::user()->id;

       if(!session('data')){

            echo "Data not set";
            $data = array(1,3,4,5);
            session(['data' => $data]);
            //Update, here it print data but if I do reload the page then always load this if section.
            $data = session('data');
            print_r($data);

       }else{

            echo "Data already set";
            $data = session('data');
            print_r($data);
       }
       exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to change session drive to something else.

Comment: same result after changing session driver in session.php

Comment: Is your `storage` directory writable? Have you set the application key? See [Installation > Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#configuration).

Comment: @GrasDouble I have windows(10), and storage directory is writeable, application key is already there in .env file, and `APP_URL=http://localhost` but I'm accessing my website like this: `http://localhost/parent/subdir/public/watch`, here `subdir` is root directory for laravel installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session data is actually stored later in the request lifecycle (search for "terminable middleware"), very late, even after the content has been sent to the user browser.

But the `exit;` in your code instantly ends the PHP script, thus the `terminate` method of the middlewares aren't executed.

More precisely, you skip executing the `terminate` method of `Session/Middleware/StartSession.php`.